# added data to the custom Dto class

Tags: spring-boot, dto

also I have a user dto class

```
class UserDto{
            Long id;
            String name;
            String email;
            String password
}
```

when user login is success, I wants to show response like this

```
{
   "user":{
      "id":"1",
      "name":"imesh"
   },
   "token":{
      "access_token":{
         "token":"bhacvyusbi",
         "expired_at":"20200210"
      },
      "refresh_token":{
         "token":"bhacvyusbi",
         "expired_at":"20200210"
      }
   }
}
```

so I have created a Response dto

```
class ResponseDto{
   UserDto user;
   AllTokenDto reponse;
}

class AllTokenDto{
TokenDto access_token;
TokenDto refresh_token;
}


class TokenDto{
   String token;
   Date expiredDate;
}
```

In here **userData** is which I am get the data from database

```
ResponseDto responseDto = new ResponseDto();
responseDto.setUser(modelMapper.map(**userData**, UserDto.class));
```

I have successfully added `ResponseDto` to `UserDto` data,
how to added tokens data to the `ResponseDto`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange to ask that question considering you similairly done it in `setUser` method. For this part, you should create a DTO for all Token and set all token you have created. And finally, write a function to set response in which the parameter is allTokenDto like this:
`responseDto.setResponse(allTokenDto);`